# How to update element value on specific URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to only update this value when the user is on a specific URL, with Javascript / jQuery

```js
// When the user is on "www.example.com"
$('#phone').val("000000");
```

Comment: If `url` is a variable, then you can do this: `url = 'www.example.com';`

Comment: Like this : $('#phone').val("00000000") url = 'www.example.com';
or what ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to return an object with the current page address / url / hostname - You can then just use this value in an if statement, to run only on a certain domain or page

```js
if (window.location.hostname === 'www.example.com') {
  $('#phone').val("000000");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Found it 
if (window.location.href.indexOf('example.php') != -1) {
}